# Ubuntu 20.10 on ThinkPad T14 (AMD). Microphone mute LED always stays on. How can I fix it or turn it off?

Tags: keyboard, thinkpad, microphone, 20.10, mute

I can mute and unmute the microphone just fine, but the white light on the mic mute button (F4) is on at all times. How can I make it respond to the muted/unmuted state of the microphone, or even just turn it off completely? It's very bright.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, perhaps this https://askubuntu.com/questions/138217/lenovo-mute-led-button-not-working

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka Thank you for that! The `alsamixer` instructions there are very helpful. I was not able to make the LED follow the muted/unmuted state of the microphone ("Follow Capture" keeps it always off, and "Follow Mute" keeps it always on), but I was able to turn it off (using the "Off" setting).

Comment: The other answer `grub` setting. If it doesn't work, perhaps ask Lenovo. I read somewhere the LED thing doesn't work as they expected, so the maker bring you another BIOS or so. If there is no switch on the wall, we can't kill or allume the room light. If it does have it, next thing we have to know is where.

Answer (score 4):

I am using ThinkPad P14s AMD, following works if you want to manually change it.

You can test to see if it works for you:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/platform\:\:micmute/brightness
```

to turn it on, and

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/platform\:\:micmute/brightness
```

to turn it off.