# T480 Disable audio mute led

Tags: thinkpad, acpi

I am running a Thinkpad T480 with Ubuntu 16.04 and i want to disable the audio mute led. (This led is on when the sound is muted, which is pretty much all the time).

So far i have followed instruction c-2 of the first answer of the following question: [Enabling Mic Mute button and light on Lenovo Thinkpads](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125367/enabling-mic-mute-button-and-light-on-lenovo-thinkpads?noredirect=1&lq=1)
This allowed me to disable the mic mute light. However it does not allow me to disable the audio mute led.

I have also patched thinkpad_acpi to allow all leds to be changed and added a soundmute value to the tpacpi_led_names.
This adds a directory in /sys/clas/leds but setting 0 in the brightness file does not turn off the led.

I used this thinkpad_acpi version for ubuntu-bionic (16.04): https://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/gavinguo/ubuntu-bionic.git/tree/drivers/platform/x86/thinkpad_acpi.c?h=hf203191v20181105b1habae6bf60e7c

Answer (score -1):

I am using a ThinkPad T480 running Linux Mint 21.1 - Cinnamon 5.6.8 - kernel 5.15.0-69-generic.

I just encountered the Audio Mute (F1) Key LED issue with the LED stuck in the On position. Pressing the key displays the Audio Status pop-up and shows mute being turned off and back on (with a second press), however the LED light and Mute do not turn off.

I was able to get the LED and Mute to turn off by launching Terminal and using the `pulseaudio` command. The first command `pulseaudio -k` will kill the PulseAudio process and the second command `pulseaudio --start` will start the PulseAudio process.

```
pulseaudio -k
pulseaudio --start
```

The LED turned off and is functioning normally with PulseAudio stopped and started.

Some context:
I am using AirPods connected via Bluetooth and playing audio using the Audacious app. The AirPods are the only variable that I have introduced recently. I have had a few system and app updates, and I have not yet verified a version change for Audacious or PulseAudio.